# Example of reading CSV file with current apache commons csv library

Tags: java, apache, csv

Can someone please provide me with an example of reading a CSV file with the Apache commons CSVParser class? I see countless examples that use the outdated (I think) API that has been impossible to find.

Everywhere I look, I see this:

```
File csvData = new File("/path/to/csv");
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvData, CSVFormat.RFC4180);
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
    ...
}
```

But nowhere can I find a jar file that has a CSVParser.parse() method that takes those parameters. The one that takes a File object, also takes a Charset parameter after it. All over the place I see the API describe that literally doesn't seem to exist. I'm guessing it was a pre-1.0 API that they removed once 1.0 was released. I've tried 1.0, 1.1. and 1.2 in my pom file dependency, but they all have the method with the Charset parameter.

Comment: Go here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi and download the Apache Commons CSV Source Code: commons-csv-1.2-src.zip And while you're on the web page look at the JavaDoc for 1.2.

Comment: @DevilsHnd That's probably the first place I looked. None of the versions there have a parse() method with just File and CSVFormat parameters. It's insane because even the frickin' documentation IN THE SOURCE FILE shows examples of using this mythical method without the Charset parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up just doing this:

```
CSVParser csvFileParser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/csv")));
```

Still blows my mind that all articles **and** official apache documentation show examples using a method that doesn't appear to exist.